# Can we please keep the link referer in the chat?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, chat

Could you guys change the link behavior in the chat so that the "shared" links will keep my userid in the url?

E.g. I throw in the chat the link: `http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/18036/127070`

And it get's converted to: `http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/swagoverflow-clothing` I want my referer (same for questions/answers)!

[image: here as image]

Comment: Just an FYI: you don't get referrers/badges for linking inside the network.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that, that may explain why I got so less of them^^