# Now that internally shared link clicks count toward publicity badges, can we please keep the user ID referral in oneboxed links posted in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, publicity-badges

I recently posted a shared link to an answer in chat that contained my user ID, in order to try and earn a publicity badge (e.g. Announcer) for sharing the link (taking a chance even if it's unlikely). I posted the bare link on its own so that it would be oneboxed, so users could see a preview of the post's content. After posting the link, I noticed that the chat system [expanded the short link to its full form and stripped out my user ID](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9069464#9069464), meaning if others click on the generated link, it won't count toward my publicity badge total for that post.

As of May 2017, the criteria for the publicity badges were [redefined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298448/377214) to include link clicks from inside the network. This means that someone can earn publicity badges if they put referral links *on the sites* and others click on them, or if they post them in chat in messages that contain other content, but *not* if they post them in chat and make use of oneboxes.

This was [previously requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266292/can-we-please-keep-the-link-referer-in-the-chat), but a staff member deemed the current behavior as by design, (probably) because at the time, the badge only considered link clicks from *outside the Stack Exchange network*, so it didn't matter. However, per the second paragraph, the badge now considers internal shared link clicks (and badges were awarded retroactively).

I don't see a philosophical reason why oneboxed links shouldn't count toward publicity badge earnings, and the technicals have changed since the time of the previous request, so can the past decision not to change it be reconsidered?

Comment: let me guess the reason "something something discourage users from spamming chat with their posts"