# Why doesn't the "Does this answer your question?" duplicate link include the user ID number?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments, publicity-badges

It seems automatically generated comments such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479826/writing-exn-k-t-as-rt#comment9400745_4479826):

> Does this answer your question? [Ramsey-Turan number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480476/ramsey-turan-number)

don't include the user's ID number.  As I understand, people can earn the ["Announcer", "Booster", and "Publicist" badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/351283) through people clicking on links with their user ID.  A highly popular feature request [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620/351283) (plus a gajillion duplicates) ask for some reward for finding duplicates.  In principle, it's possible to edit the comment to include one's user ID, but in practice, it's too much of a hassle to be worthwhile.

I'm just wondering if there's a reason why it's not designed to automatically include the user ID, to help them earn these badges.

**Question**: Why doesn't the "Does this answer your question?" duplicate link include the user ID number?

I understand the comment is auto-deleted if the question is closed as a duplicate; perhaps this is the reason.

Comment: Before the switch to HTTPS, we didn't allow links within the network to contribute to those badges, so using a share link on the same site did nothing. And those possible duplicate comments long pre-date the change to those badges. I imagine just nobody ever thought of converting them to share links.

Comment: The same applies to [oneboxed links in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372422/now-that-internally-shared-link-clicks-count-toward-publicity-badges-can-we-ple): the user ID gets stripped out.

Answer (score 5):

A *Does this answer your question?* comment would ideally only be clicked by 5 reviewers - assuming the post is correctly signaled; promptly reviewed and; effectively closed. So it would still be 15 clicks short of the announcer badge, before [*"The comment will be automatically deleted if the question is closed as a duplicate"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757).

Another reason is that the comment is system generated, meaning the least you can ask of someone to earn a badge is a conscious <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> ...

As for [rewarding the duplicate finders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048) (specifically the first user that flags or close votes a question) it has been marked [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) but the recent change of awarding [multiple steward badges per review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360270/665544) already goes a long way in rewarding reviewers, so adding an additional publicity badge doesn't seem the most adequate choice.

Finally the change to SSL (see [Announcer badge spike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295575/665544)) made the badges somewhat less interesting altogether because it changed the end they were initially designed for.

Comment: It helps more if you find *more* questions that are duplicates of a single original, but still ...